# Least Squares Equation (Change in Estimated Value)

Tags: arithmetic

The specified Least Square regression line is `Price=5.2+2.5*Value`

If I was told that the estimated `Value` had changed from `$1.4` to `$1.7`, How would this effect the Price?

Im guessing substituting $1.7 with value will give me the right answer?, or am I looking for calculating the input change here of `Y=mΔx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
P&=5.2+2.5V\\
\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial V}&=2.5\\
\dfrac{\Delta P}{\Delta V}&=2.5\\
\Delta P &=2.5\times \Delta V\\
\Delta P &=2.5\times 0.3\\
&=\$\;0.75
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @Inquest, but what happened to the 5.2 in the second step?

Comment: The derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: Why cant I use the Following calculation, how is what was calculated different to the below..

**So an increase in the input from x to x+Δx induces a change in output of mΔx. For an estimated regression equation we estimate this change by mΔx.**

Comment: I actually got the same result by calculating mΔx, I just want to figure out how though.... Thanks Guys!

Comment: @IAML, Partial derivatives is a way of generalizing what you did. Since the equation is linear, it doesn't matter which approach you take.